winrt/Microsoft.ReactNative.Composition.h: No such file or directory
ReactNative is missing a file. Is there any way to include that file?
yarn react-native run-windows failed with
yarn run v1.22.19

√ Restoring NuGet packages 
 √ Auto-linking...
Success: No auto-linking changes necessary. (11ms)
 √ Found Solution: C:\Users\Roma\WebstormProjects\MyApp2\windows\MyApp2.sln
 i Build configuration: Debug
 i Build platform: x64
 × Building Solution: (компиляция исходного файла "pch.cpp")...
 × Build failed with message C:\Users\Roma\WebstormProjects\MyApp2\windows\MyApp2\pch.h(24,10): error C1083: �� ������� ������� ���� ���������: winrt/Microsoft.ReactNative.Composition.h: No such file or directory, [C:\Users\Roma\WebstormProjects\
MyApp2\windows\MyApp2\MyApp2.vcxproj]. Check your build configuration.
Command failed. Re-run the command with --logging for more information.
error Command failed with exit code 2302.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

